# How much sugar does it take to get "cidery" off flavors.

Tags: off-flavor

I've added a bunch of sugar to brews before, upwards of 30% of the grain weight and I'm yet to get any cidery flavors.  You always hear sugar causes cider, but all I've ever noticed is a thinner body.

Has anybody ever had a noticable flavor effect of adding sugar, intentionally or unintentionally, if so, how much did you add?

Comment: I believe this also depends on the type of sugar used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never really gotten "cidery" flavors from adding sugars. From what I've read the sugar needs to be from 40% - 50% to get these flavors.

I will say that adding too much sugar to a brew can give you some "hot" alcohol flavors that take time to mellow.